# JSON with additional content at top of file

Tags: r, json

I am trying to read this url into R as a JSON: https://comtrade.un.org/Data/cache/reporterAreas.json

I see that there is additional content at the top of the file, wrapping the content I am after. A sample of the file looks as follows:

```
{
  "more": false,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "all",
      "text": "All"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "text": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "text": "Albania"
    }
  ]
}
```

Trying to read using:

```
x <- GET(url)
fromJSON(rawToChar(x$content))
```

doesn't work throwing error: `unexpected character '<ef>'`. I assume this is seeing the `[`.

I also tried `download.file(url, file)`, calling `fromJSON(file)`, but that threw the error `unexpected character 'r'`, which I am guessing is from "results"

I assume this is just some header formatting for the JSON (apologies, I don't do much with JSON files), and there is am option for dealing with it either via `GET()` or `fromJSON()`, but I can't see anything in the docs. None of the examples that i have seen describing how to pull JSON from url have this format.

When I call `class(rawToChar(x$content))` it shows as a `chr vector`, so I could clean that eliminating the `{"more": false,"results": [` and `]}`, but that seems wonky for what looks like a standard format.

If someone can show me how to import this correctly, i would welcome it. Also welcome a more useful question title which describes this issue more effectively.

Comment: The `jsonlite::fromJSON()` function expects a character vector, not a filename.  It is complaining that you are passing it the string "reporterAreas.json" to decode.  You can pass it a file, e.g. `file( "reporterAreas.json")`, but not a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<ef>` character is the first byte of a byte-order mark translated to UTF-8.  The other bytes are `<bb><bf>`.

When I download the file using `download.file()` and then decode it using `jsonlite::read_json()`, it gives a warning about the BOM, but appears to read the rest of the file without an error.  You should try that.